# Generators of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ - what is $\tau(\zeta_n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, primitive-roots

I  am trying to understand the structure of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})\simeq Z_n^*$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ - it would be great if someone could me understand the generators in this group so I can understand the structure

Is it true $\tau (\zeta_n)=\zeta^n$? How can we show the existence of such generators?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint, maybe it will be helpful. Ignore the vector space structure of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ for the moment, and just think of the cyclic group (under complex multiplication) $\{1,\zeta_n,\zeta_n^2,\dots,\zeta_n^{n-1}\}$.

Each of these is a root (in fact they are all of them) of the rational polynomial $x^n - 1$.

Thus an element of $\text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q)$ must send such a root to another root, and since they are automorphisms of $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$, they induce automorphisms of $\langle \zeta_n\rangle \cong \Bbb Z_n$.

Well, since $\Bbb Z_n$ is cyclic (generated by $1$), to determine an automorphism $\phi$ of $\Bbb Z_n$, it suffices to know where $1$ is mapped to. The corresponding automorphism is then given by:

$k \mapsto ak$, where $a = \phi(1)$.

So ask yourself, which choices of $a \in \Bbb Z_n$ lead to an automorphism $\phi$? Convince yourself $a$ has to be invertible under multiplication modulo $n$, and that this is also sufficient.

Then take the *additive* structure of $(\Bbb Z_n,+)$ and transfer (via the imaginary exponential map) it to the *multiplicative* structure of $\langle (\zeta_n\rangle, \cdot)$.

That is, the elements of $\text{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q)$ you want are of the form $\zeta_n \mapsto (\zeta_n)^a$, with $a$ as in $\phi$ above.